# Problema ao usar InteractJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou com um problema ao tentar usar como biblioteca o [InteractJS](http://interactjs.io/).

Neste momento o [meu código](https://jsfiddle.net/FMCalisto/nkhp067r/), como podem observar, está a invocar os ficheiros necessários para a correcta execução do exemplo:

```
<link href="css/drag-drop.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

e

```
<script src="js/drag-drop.js"></script>
```

No entanto o comportamento não se verifica.

O código **HTML** está como exemplificado na página:

```
<div id="no-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"> #no-drop </div>

    <div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"> #yes-drop </div>

    <div id="outer-dropzone" class="dropzone">
        #outer-dropzone
    <div id="inner-dropzone" class="dropzone">#inner-dropzone</div>

</div>
```

Não consigo compreender o que estarei a fazer de errado.

Comment: Você incluiu um monte de biblioteca que nem estão sendo usados no projeto, o angular js, é um exemplo. Você nem chamou o ng-app, para que incluir a biblioteca, é só para poluir?

Comment: Veja no seu console do navegador, que tem um monte de arquivo com erro 404.

Comment: O JS Fiddle tem um campo para você incluir as bibliotecas externas.

Comment: @IvanFerrer a versão do Protótipo que está aqui a ser usada como exemplo do problema é a **Não-Funcional** sendo que existe outra **Funcional** que tem mais algumas bibliotecas, daí estas estarei ai.

Comment: @IvanFerrer irei ver de que forma posso colocar as bibliotecas externas no campo do JS Fiddle de que fala.

Comment: Então, crie um jsfiddle somente com o problema apresentado e funcional para que alguém possa ajudá-lo.